# How to expose a module (sinon, chai) as global variables with correct types?

Tags: typescript, sinon, chai, sinon-chai, typescript-typings

In Js tests, **mocha**, **chai** and **sinon** are commonly exposed as global variables to save some `import`, usually via karma plugins.

Installing mocha typings goes well, mocha `describe`, `it`... are correctly exposed as global variables with correct types.

However, trying to also expose chai and sinon typings as global vars (`typings i --global --save-dev sinon`) yields me a :

> typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "sinon" as a global module, but it looks like an external module.`

I tried to write a typings file myself, but I don't have access to those libs typings (import ?)...

Is it possible ? How should I do it ? And will it work with sinon-chai ?

Answer (score -2):

> Attempted to compile "sinon" as a global module

The file is declared as a module. I recommend just installing it as a module and then editing the file manually to make it global.

Comment: Editing manually a file coming from a package manager ? Of course it's doable, but I'd rather a more scalable approach. Thanks anyway !